# Link the static versions of the Boost libraries using CMake

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I've got both the static and the dynamic versions of the boost libraries in /usr/lib. Now I'd like CMake to prefer the static versions during the linkage of my executable. What can I do?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

In your `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED ...)
```

Where I have `...`, you optionally put the names of the libraries you want to use, and then `target_link_libraries(targetname ${Boost_LIBRARIES})` later below. If you have a fairly recent distribution of CMake, it should work exactly as advertised. I do it exactly this way in my own projects.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a full example of CMAKEFILE,For example, include boost program options

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(your_project)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON)
find_package(Boost 1.70 COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)   
add_executable(your_project main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(your_project Boost::program_options)
```

references:

[cmake documents about BOOST](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/FindBoost.html)