# Linking boost & mygui 3.2.1 undefined symbol

Tags: user-interface, boost, linker, ogre, undefined-symbol

I am trying to install myGui 3.2.1 on kubuntu. However while linking the files the following problems occur:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Demo_Colour.dir/DemoKeeper.cpp.o: undefined reference to enter code here/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Demo_Gui.dir/DemoKeeper.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command/usr line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Demo_Controllers.dir/DemoKeeper.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Demo_Console.dir/DemoKeeper.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

I guess there is a problem linking with boost and I found some ways to solve it but those solutions were only for archlinux and didn't work for me. Anyway I have looked through the CMAKE files of myGui and couldn't find anything about boost...

I would appreciate every form of help!

Answer (score 0):

> I have looked through the CMAKE files of myGui and couldn't find anything about boost...

You obviously need to link with appropriate Boost libraries. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6646518/50617) may help.

Comment: Thank you! I've already tried that but then CMAKE is making problems: Cannot specify link libraries for target
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so" which is not built by this project.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was fixed in git repository.
Boost is not used in MyGUI, but when you build MyGUI using OgrePlatform OGRE require boost for it's headers.