# Dynamically Linking boost with Cmake

Tags: boost, linker, cmake, dynamic-linking

I've checked several questions, yet none of the answers helped my case. Here are the ones I checked

[How to link C++ program with Boost using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897839/how-to-link-c-program-with-boost-using-cmake)

[Whats the proper way to link Boost with CMake and Visual Studio in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023913/whats-the-proper-way-to-link-boost-with-cmake-and-visual-studio-in-windows)

[Error linking Boost with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270246/error-linking-boost-with-cmake)

I've built Boost 1.61 with

```
b2 variant=debug,release link=static,shared threading=single,multi
```

Under stage/lib, I have all dlls and libs. Following Boost::System libs are present under stage/lib

```
boost_system-vc140-mt-1_61.dll
boost_system-vc140-mt-1_61.lib
boost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_61.dll
boost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_61.lib
libboost_system-vc140-mt-1_61.lib
libboost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_61.lib
```

I want to compile a basic boost asio example (which requires system lib from boost). I make my cmake file with cmake-gui in windows, then generate VS2015 project files. After attempting to build the project, following error occurs.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: boost-asio, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>  main.cpp
2>  Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately. For example:
2>  - add -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 to the compiler command line; or
2>  - add _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 to your project's Preprocessor Definitions.
2>  Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 (i.e. Windows XP target).
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_61.lib'
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The contents of my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

project(boost-asio)

find_package(Boost 1.61.0 COMPONENTS system REQUIRED)

# set cmake variables
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/bin)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)

# definitions
add_definitions(-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK=1)

# set sources
set(SOURCES src/main.cpp)


# manage compilation and linkage
if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_executable(boost-asio ${SOURCES})
    target_link_libraries(boost-asio ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

    message(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    message(${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

Please note that the definition in the cmake source is added according to an answer in some question I checked. FindBoost finds the boost library, here is an output from cmake-gui

```
Boost version: 1.61.0
Found the following Boost libraries:
  system
C:/Boost/boost_1_61_0
optimizedC:/Boost/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/boost_system-vc140-mt-1_61.libdebugC:/Boost/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/boost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_61.lib
```

Now there are two problems here. First, it can not find the library and second, although it clearly directs the linker to link dynamically, it still looks for static library. I don't know if these problems are related. How to solve this problem? How to dynamically link Boost using Cmake?

**EDIT1**: Here is the code I am using, if you want to test it out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

int main() {

    boost::asio::io_service ioservice;

    boost::asio::deadline_timer t(ioservice, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));

    t.wait();

    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Boost_USE_*` variables should be set **before** `find_package(Boost)` call for have an effect.

Comment: Tried building after adding `find_package(Boost)` right before `if(Boost_FOUND)`, it doesn't seem to have an effect

Comment: You need to clear CMake cache for regenerate result of `find_package()`.

Comment: I deleted cache and re-configured and regenerated the project files. Still the same.

Comment: Shouldn't you add `asio` as a component in `find_package()` since that is what you want not just `system`??

Comment: Asia is not a linked component. It's a header-only library depending on some other boost libraries as far as I know.

Comment: Since you are building a 32 bit application did you build/install 32 bit boost binaries?

Comment: According to boost documentation, the default is 32 bit as I didn't specify the address model while building the boost.

Comment: Configuring the cmake file to link statically worked after fixing the errors pointed out in the comments. However, I still couldn't make dynamic linkage work.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following flags in your CMakeLists.txt solves the problem:

```
add_definitions( -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB )
add_definitions( -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK )
```

Comment: Best way: use add `target_compile_definitions(<your_target> PRIVATE BOOST_<component>_DYN_LINK)`