# cmake does not find boost header on linux

Tags: c++, linux, boost, cmake

Boost header files are on `/usr/include/boost`.

In `CMakeLists.txt` I include the folder with `include_directories`

```
include_directories(/usr/include /usr/include/boost/  
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr)
```

However, `cmake` insists in not finding header files. The problem arises in `intrusive_ptr.hpp`, which includes `#include <boost/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.hpp`:

```
boost/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory
/usr/include/boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp
```

My guess is it does not like `boost/smart_ptr/` prefix.

So, `include_directories` did not work.

**CMake Error:**

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1245   
(message):
Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
Boost's headers.
```

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not CMake that's not finding the headers, that's a compiler error...

Comment: Have you tried giving the BOOST_ROOT hint? Like `cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=/usr/include/`? If this does not work, which compiler are you using and how did you install Boost?

Answer (score 1):

While I do not know what failed in your case, I'd recommend to simply use [find_package](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/find_package.html) with the included [FindBoost.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake) file:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Done

Comment: I couldnt use it simply because find_package does not find Boost.

Comment: @MertKoksal that makes the answer unhelpful, but you should now see what's wrong with the question

Comment: @MertKoksal What exactly is the output/error from CMake?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using 3.3 cmake version, which support target_include_directories.

Even target_link_library should help here which gives the include path free if we link the library.

[How do you add boost libraries in CMakeLists.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646405/how-do-you-add-boost-libraries-in-cmakelists-txt)