# How can I link Boost to my CMake project on Windows

Tags: boost, cmake

I searched everywhere but most of the answers are relevant to Linux, not many use CLion on Windows.

So I extracted boost_1_60_0 into `C:\` and now my path for the boost root folder is

```
C:\boost_1_60_0
```

I got the CMakeLists.txt file where I'm trying to set the root directory of boost and include it, but it doesn't recognize it:

```
set(Boost_Path "C:/boost_1_60_0")
find_package(Boost 1.60.0)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "It works!")
endif()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read this for reference: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html
You have to set BOOST_ROOT

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add boost libraries in CMakeLists.txt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646405/how-do-you-add-boost-libraries-in-cmakelists-txt)

Comment: It refuses to work for me. this is what I added to CMakeLists: http://pastebin.com/eWN2F878

Comment: What is output (add it to the question post) of your script? `I extracted boost_1_60_0 into C` - **extracted** or **installed**? First means extracting sources for futher build and installation. You need to have Boost *installed*.