# Specify library path via compiler environment variables or command line flags in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, environment-variables, include-path

When using a library outside of the project, e.g. [boost](http://www.boost.org/) or [Guidelines Support Library](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL), how should we specify the paths related to that library?

- add the paths to the `LIBRARY_PATH` and `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variables used by the compiler.
- define a environment variable (e.g. `GSL_PATH`) and then
  add `-L` and `-isystem` flags in the makefile of each project.

Is there a best practice for this? What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach? Consider the need to compile and use the project on other systems.

For various reasons the libraries are installed in a custom path

Comment: This is subjective, but—I strongly suggest using flags.  Flags are explicit, and environment variables are more annoying to debug.  If you use flags, you can copy a command out of a make invocation and run it in your terminal window.  With environment variables, you can't.  I'm currently working with a build system that uses lots of environment variables at work, and it's a total pain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cmake for configuring your project

And find boost and gsl with cmake

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/module/FindGSL.html
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html

[Example for boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646405/how-do-you-add-boost-libraries-in-cmakelists-txt)