# Cmake build with extern libraires

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, arm, cross-compiling

I am beginner in arm build.
I want to build this code for armel platform.
I have a code:

```
#include <boost/container/flat_map.hpp>
#include <boost/container/flat_set.hpp>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

Also I have Cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.10 FATAL_ERROR)
project(test CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-10)

set(SRC_FILES test.cpp)

add_definitions(-DBOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY)
add_definitions(-DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED)
add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB)
add_definitions(-DBOOST_NO_RTTI)
add_definitions(-DBOOST_NO_TYPEID)
add_definitions(-DBOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_THREADS)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_FILES})
```

I install nlohmann library into:

```
/usr/local/include/nlohmann/json.hpp
```

After I generate make and make:

```
/home/test-machine/project-dir/test/test.cpp:3:10: fatal error: nlohmann/json.hpp: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.dir/build.make:82: CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:103: all] Error 2
```

Why I have this error. Help me pls!!!

Comment: non-native compilers don't usually use the system include paths by default, you probably need to specify `/usr/local/include` as an include directory

Comment: You can do that by using the command "include_directories(/usr/local/include)" : https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html

Comment: Thanks! I test it on real code but I have many notice with ld. I have notice like this ```/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/10/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/power-control.dir/src/power-control.cpp.o: in function `sdbusplus::bus::bus::process_discard()':
power-control.cpp:(.text._ZN9sdbusplus3bus3bus15process_discardEv[_ZN9sdbusplus3bus3bus15process_discardEv]+0x98): undefined reference to `sdbusplus::exception::SdBusError::SdBusError(int, char const*, sdbusplus::SdBusInterface*) ``` I dont have exec file after make.

Comment: https://json.nlohmann.me/integration/cmake/

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the more correct way would be to properly install library and then use the `find_package` directive.

```
# CMakeLists.txt
find_package(nlohmann_json 3.2.0 REQUIRED)
...
add_library(foo ...)
...
target_link_libraries(foo PRIVATE nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json)
```

Example above is a part of [nlohmann Cmake documentation](https://json.nlohmann.me/integration/cmake/).

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your code. If you don't mind I'll be using newer CMake.

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(test LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

add_executable(foobar)

target_sources(foobar PRIVATE
    test.cpp
)

target_compile_definitions(foobar PRIVATE
    BOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY
    BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED
    BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB
    BOOST_NO_RTTI
    BOOST_NO_TYPEID
    BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_THREADS
)
```

To specify your ARM compiler use a CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE. If you specify your compiler in your CMake code it might be nice at first but will cause issues later down the road.

```
# arm.cmake

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-10)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabi-g-10)
```

Now when you make your project do the following:

```
cd <your-project>
cmake -S . -B build/ -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=arm.cmake
```

Now the issue remaining with your code is that you have no way to find your third party dependencies.

You need to add code to find/link `boost`. And find/link `nlohmann/json`

### Boost

[How do you add Boost libraries in CMakeLists.txt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646405/how-do-you-add-boost-libraries-in-cmakelists-txt)

### nlohmann/json

This repo actually has pretty good docs on how to add the library to your CMake project.

https://github.com/nlohmann/json#cmake

TLDR:

To use this library from a CMake project, you can locate it directly with find_package() and use the namespaced imported target from the generated package configuration:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
find_package(nlohmann_json 3.2.0 REQUIRED)
...
add_library(foo ...)
...
target_link_libraries(foo PRIVATE nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json)
```

Answer (score 0):

With non native compilers, you must configure the whole environment.

In fact, when doing so, I would highly suggest using a [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html).

Using that you can setup your toolchain, or even multiple toolchain.

Then, for the environment, I would suggest installing the libraries using their installer and let CMake find it. Take nlohmann json for example:

```
nlohmann_json$ mkdir build
nlohmann_json$ cd build
nlohmann_json/build$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/youruser/arm-prefix -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=yourtoolchain.cmake
nlohmann_json/build$ cmake --build . --target install
```

Those command will setup nlohmann json with your toolchain, and will install it in a new prefix.

Then, in your project, you can have such toolchain and such CMakeLists.txt file:

toolchain.cmake:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-10)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-10)
set(CMAKE_STAGING_PREFIX /home/youruser/arm-prefix)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH /home/youruser/arm-prefix)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(test CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(test)

find_package(nlohmann_json REQUIRED)

target_sources(test PRIVATE test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test PUBLIC nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json)
```

The magic lies in the prefix path. When you set an install prefix to install libraries into and you set the same prefix path when building your project, `find_package` suddenly works. If you use the same toolchain between those two projects, then CMake will detect those two packages as compatible.

Notice that I also explicitly didn't used variables in the CMakeLists file. This is because variables are a pain point of CMake and results in unexpected behaviour. In normal CMake file to define a project, their usage should be rare.

Also, stay away from `add_definitions`, `link_directories`, `include_directories` and all of those. *Always* prefer `target_compile_definitions`, `target_link_libraries`, `target_include_directories` and other target based commands.

---

As for boost I don't know their build system very well. There might be ways to cross compile the library and install it, but my knowledge ends here.