# Problem with linking Boost in CLion on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, boost, mingw, clion

I need to use boost asio under CLion IDE.

When I compile my project I get error

```
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -g  CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/main.cpp.obj -o HelloWorld.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libHelloWorld.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lBoost  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lBoost
```

What can be the problem here?

I followed Best Solution from this thread: https://itecnote.com/tecnote/c-setup-boost-in-clion/.
I installed MinGW distro by Stephan T. Lavavej with boost prebuilt.
Then I added following lines to my CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR c:/mingw/include/)
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR c:/mingw/lib/) find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED) include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(HelloWorld main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(HelloWorld Boost)
```

UPD: Source code (only asio header):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: cannot find -lBoost

Comment: Can you post your complete CMakeLists.txt? And also the code, so we can try compiling it ourselves.

Comment: Did it. There is only single import of asio

Comment: Ah. `target_link_libraries(HelloWorld Boost)` probably interprets `Boost` as a literal library (file)name, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6646518/2752075

Comment: You need to add `find_package(Boost)`