# how can I make a shared library work on different versions of libraries it depends (using cmake)?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, shared-libraries

I wrapped my program (which depends on Boost) into a shared library (say `libabc.so`), which works fine one my machine.

When I copied the `libabc.so` to another machine that has different Boost version installed, the compiler could not link `libabc.so` to that version, and when I typed `ldd libabc.so` it said that the boost library was not found.

How can I solve that using cmake?
Is there a way to wrap the libraries it depends all together in one file `libabc.so`?

---

I know this is a entry level question and probably there're a few similar questions already on SO which I failed to find out, but this question [Link the static versions of the Boost libraries using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176035/link-the-static-versions-of-the-boost-libraries-using-cmake) seems not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link the static versions of the Boost libraries using CMake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176035/link-the-static-versions-of-the-boost-libraries-using-cmake)

Comment: What `ldd libabc.so` shows you? Particularly, how boost library names are look like? Are they have any version in their names?

Comment: @zaufi thanks for the reply, it says `libboost_system.so.1.54.0 => not found` and the actual version installed on the other machine is 1.58

Answer (score 1):

Use boost bcp to wrap your boost version in another namespace and then you can have several boost version co-exist in the same application.

Comment: thanks for replying, actually I could not know which boost version is installed on other machines (and I probably do not care), is there a way to make it work on whatever boost version installed on other machines?

Comment: Yes, if you use boost bcp and wrap your boost in another namespace like I wrote in the answer. Then it will not matter.

Comment: To clarify, you will have to distribute your bcp-namespace-version of the boost library with your libabc.so.