# Add a library in a linux executable compilation

Tags: linux, compilation, addition, executable

I am compiling a program on ubuntu 14.04 which requires a library share libboost_system.so.1.55.0. I would like to be able to share my executable on another Linux version but the library is not there. Is it possible to add a library directly during the compilation so that my executable is functional on several linux distributions.

I am a newbie in linux programming. I use the command make -j

thank you

Comment: you have to link it statically to your app. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176035/link-the-static-versions-of-the-boost-libraries-using-cmake

Comment: What compiler do you use? gcc?